# jquery else if statement doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, if-statement

I want to show a warning message if user does not complete entire form but it seems not to work as I want. The jQuery .each method only collects data from the first input field. If I leave the first field empty it works correctly but if I fill only the first field and leave other fields empty it shows success which is wrong.

```
// send message on click
$("#submit").click(function() {

    // store values
    var data = $("#form").serialize();

    $(":input, textarea").each(function() {

        // if empty show warning
        if ( $(this).val() === "" ) {
            $(".message-fail").fadeIn(500);
        }

        // if not empty send message
        else if ( !$(this).val() ) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "mail.php",
                    data: data,
                    success: function() {
                        $(".message-sent").fadeIn(500);
                    }
                });
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Do you really want to do an ajax call for every text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following process:

**BUT I THINK YOU DON'T NEED AJAX FOR EVERY FIELD**

```
if ($.trim(this.value).length) { // if value exists
    $(".message-fail").fadeIn(500);
} else { // if no value exists, here no need to elseif
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: data,
        success: function() {
            $(".message-sent").fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
}
```

Explanation:

`$.trim(this.value)` -> check for value exists

or can also use (first one is better)

`$.trim($(this).val()).length` -> checks for value exists

Comment: `trim` isn't supported in all the browsers... (IE < 9, Opera < 10.5 ...) [source- mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: Ohh, and please use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`, and you can remove the `length` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

in this line `else if ( !$(this).val() )` there is wrong condition i.e. `!$(this).val()` please make it correct it will work....

Answer (score 0):

you need to place "else" outside of "each", because first valid input will post form :)
make a flag variable, make checks inside of each... but it's better to use simple loop. and after checks complited make another check of your flag and post if it's ok